# Azure API Management - Return JSON response without sending to backend service

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to create an API in Azure API Management where I just want to set up a simple API that returns a JSON response with a 200 status without sending it to any backend services.
I found a way to do this through mocking but wondering if there is a better approach to this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out by adding the  policy in Inbound Processing:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>{
                "test_key": "hello"
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```